# Managing PushSubscriptions within shared browsers

Tags: service-worker, web-push

Working on ironing out some UX considerations around a push notification system using [WebPush](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Push_API) and [ServiceWorkers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API). Additionally, this system should gracefully handle multiple users sharing the same browser.

More concretely, I have the following constraints:

1) A user should not be able to see notifications which are not intended for them.

2) The state of a user's push subscription should be opaque to and immutable by other users. i.e. the state of my push subscription should not be based on the behavior/actions of anybody but my own.

Satisfying the first constraint was quite straightforward. I decided to store the currently logged-in user id in [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) and include the id of the intended user within the push payload. It is then straightforward to only show the push notification to the user if those 2 ids match.

However, satisfying constraint 2 has proved to be quite elusive. So far I've tried:

1) One-to-one mapping between users and push subscriptions. This was the first thing I tried, as it struck me as the most natural mapping. However, this ends up falling flat on its face as creating a new push subscription will invalidate the subscription for the previous user, thus requiring the original user to create another subscription on subsequent logins, thus failing the second constraint.

2) Shared push subscription. This has the benefit of not invalidating the push subscriptions, so subsequent logins for the original user will behave as expected. However, none of the subsequent users will actually need to grant permission to the browser, thus failing the second constraint.

3) Even if I was able to get something working with one of the above 2 options, there is still nothing preventing another user from simply going to the browser settings and disallowing notifications, thus nuking all push subscriptions. However, I imagine that this is just something I will have to live with that will have no elegant solution.

I'm certain there have been many brilliant minds working on the above problem, so I'm all ears with regards to how constraint 2 above has effectively been satisfied.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when I was developing Pushpad. We tried different solutions and some of them, such as the many to many relation between users and browsers, became a nightmare very soon. So I would recommend the following approach, which proved to be the best one for us.

**Each subscription (endpoint) is a device (browser) and can be associated at most to one user at a time**. **Whenever possible try to keep data associated to users and not to devices. In this way a subscription (endpoint) can be transferred to a different user** and you don't loose data when the endpoint expires or gets  replaced. Then when you need to send a notification filter your audience based on the user data, find the recipients and send the notification to the associated devices.

The only data that you may want to associate to devices are device preferences and device preferences are global to all the users that use that browser. This is consistent with the fact that the browser permission (allow / block) is global to all users.

The above solution partially meets your requirements:

> 1) A user should not be able to see notifications which are not intended for them.

Yes:

- when a user logs out you can remove the association between the user and the device
- when a browser (user) logs in with a different account on your website you associate the device to the new user (and you remove the previous association)

> 2) The state of a user's push subscription should be opaque to and immutable by other users.

Yes, because you don't keep data associated to the device. You associate data to the users in your database.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Unless I'm missing something, this seems like none but the first user would actually have to allow browser notifications for all subsequent users to receive them? To clarify, User 1 allows browser notifications, so create push subscription and associate it to user 1. Now user 1 logs out, so disassociate push subscription from them. When user 2 logs in, the browser will see no need to prompt them to allow notifications, so the push subscription will be automatically registered to them.

Comment: @BrentHronik Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to satisfy both constraints. You will need to choose either the one-to-one mapping (1) or the shared push subscription (2). You cannot use the browser to deliver your push notifications and at the same time expect certain behaviour (w.r.t. permissions, nuking) from that very same browser...

Comment: If it is not possible to satisfy both constraints, how would it be possible to satisfy just the seconds constraint?